# Does visiting chat count towards Enthusiast and Fanatic?

Tags: support, chat, activity-badges

The [Enthusiast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/39/enthusiast)/[Fanatic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/53/fanatic) badges require users to visit the site for 30/100 consecutive days, respectively. Users must do this actively in some way; i.e., it doesn't count if a user writes a bot/script that just loads the front page, or anything like that.

Well, now we have [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com).  The public beta chat has `meta.stackoverflow.com` right there in its URL.  Does participating in chat  — again, discounting bots and scripts — but not visiting the parent site count as activity towards the badge requirement?

Of course, this only applies to Meta, until [per-site chat is introduced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/chat-now-in-public-beta/).  Assume for the sake of argument that there are no machines out there that can pass the Turing test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not.

Comment: Well, [that was easy](http://media.photobucket.com/image/staples%20easy%20button/jinkles/staples-easy-button-1.png).